# Convert Intellij additionalParameters in Eclipse Format

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, intellij-idea

i started to work on a new project, unfortunately they use all IntelliJ ultimate edition and they won't provide me a license, so i have to use eclipse. 
They provided me a file of additionalParameters in structure like this:

```
<additionalParameters>
    <param>
      <option name="******" value="******" />
      <option name="******" value="******" />
      <option name="******" value="******" />
    </param>
    <param>
        <option name="******" value="******" />
        <option name="******" value="******" />
        <option name="******" value="******" />
      </param>
</additionalParameters>
```

how can I create an equivalent run in eclipse? 
thanks

[image]

Comment: Please give some more context. What are these parameters for? Launch configurations, project properties, code formatting, ... ? Can you ask them for a screenshot of the UI where these parameters are?

Also did you try IntelliJ Community?

Comment: Hello Thanks for the answer, i added the screen up in the main thread, yeah i would like to use also community edition but i am getting same problem, because they use directlu springboot config, and i don't have it in community.